# Salesforce Apex - Metadata API fails throwing error 'Cannot set module to a nonexistent module. <SObject> does not exist.'

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I have created a custom metdata type with 2 custom fields (object__c and field__c). The purpose of my apex code is to create a custom metadata record with object name and/or field names. Even though it is working fine for standard objects, but for custom object (e.g. POC__Disc_Channel__c where 'Disc_Channel__c' is the custom object, 'POC' is the org namespace), it fails to create the custom metdata record. It throws the below error.

**'problem=Cannot set module to a nonexistent module. Disc_Channel does not exist., problemType=Error, success=false'**

**The fullName of the custom metadata record is set as follows -
'ObjectPermissionSetting.POCTwitch__Discord_Channel__c_All'**

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Did you include the namespace in the metadata?

Comment: @sfdcfox, Yes...both in custom metadata (POC__ObjectPermissionSetting) and in the object (POC__Disc_Channel__c) where POC is the namespace. So the full name of the custom metadata record comes as 'POC__ObjectPermissionSetting.POCTwitch__Dis_Channel__c_All' where I am appending '_All' for a business requirement.

Comment: How are you creating the custom metadata record? Aren't you mixing two namespaces here? "POC" and "POCTwitch"?

Comment: The namespace is POCTwitch only....By mistake, the earlier one was typed as POC.